# Optimal DPI Setting in Olympus OMD EM5 mii?

Tags: camera-settings, megapixels, file-size, dpi

I had been using the default 350 dpi, but the resulting files are too small to sell to most stock photography sites online. For a standard print at 300dpi, they are great. A bit low for my metal art, which usually prints at 600 dpi, and the industrial provider I use for canvas prints requests 1600 dpi (no typo). My question is since I can change this setting in the camera itself, so that I don't have to stitch a panorama for every shot I want to list on a stock site, what should I change this to to get the most out of my camera? It's supposed to be capable of standard shots of over 17megapixels, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Thank you!

Comment: 1600 dpi for a canvas, sure, why not ! But if you think that you need 1600 pixels per inch (ppi), given 20 by 30 inch canvas, you will only need 20×1600×30×1600 = 1536 megapixels (no typo). 1600 dpi is probably the number of dot per inch that they use for printing, similar to the number of ink dot a inkjet printer can produce :) What is the name of your industrial provider ?

Comment: There's a huge difference between pixels per inch (ppi) and dots per inch (dpi). Please see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-do-i-generate-high-quality-prints-with-an-ink-jet-printer/1716#1716 and also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27170/what-does-pixels-per-inch-mean-exactly/27172#27172 and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/what-does-dpi-mean

Answer (score 0):

> I had been using the default 350 dpi, but the resulting files are too small to sell to most stock photography sites online.

The ppi settings has nothing to do with the real photo size. You can have 72 ppi or 300. If you have enough Megapixels you are fine.

Note that the unit is ppi, **pixels** per inch, not dpi (**dots** per inch). dpi is a printer resolution unit, that defines how small the dot of ink is, not how many pixels you have per inch in the printed photo.

> For a standard print at 300dpi, they are great. A bit low for my metal art, which usually prints at 600 dpi, and the industrial provider I use for canvas prints requests 1600 dpi (no typo).

This is an example on how you are confusing the units. You *print* in a printer that has 600 or 1600 dots of ink each inch. But you need to send the information on the size of your photo in pixels per inch.

In a standard offset sheeted print (a magazine for example) you use laser generated dots on a plate at 2400 dpi, and you use a 300 ppi file.

Regarding your question... you do not need to do anithing.